# Remove css IMG style for images in a DIV

Tags: css

I want to set a different IMG style for images in a special DIV. Here is my structure

```
<div class=content>
   <div class=contact>
   </div>
</div>
```

Then I have a IMG style for the content div like this

```
div.content img {
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
    -moz-border-radius:10px;
    -khtml-border-radius:10px;
    border-radius:10px;
    padding:5px;
    margin-right:15px;
    margin-top:8px;
    box-shadow:0 0px 25px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 200px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.0);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.0);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.0);
    -o-transform: scale(1.0);
    transform: scale(1.0); 
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 500ms;
}
```

What I want to achieve is to set a different IMG style for the Contact DIV but it doesnt work.

```
div.contact img
{

}
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Your example should work if your `div.contact img` is loaded later than your first selector. Otherwise, increase the specificity of your second, such as something like `div.content .contact img`.

Comment: contact it is loaded after the content. Tried div.content .contact img but it doesnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Created a fiddle for you. Is this what you are looking for http://jsfiddle.net/4DpBV/1/.
You can use `>` property

```
.content {
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
    -moz-border-radius:10px;
    -khtml-border-radius:10px;
    border-radius:10px;
    padding:5px;
    margin-right:15px;
    margin-top:8px;
    box-shadow:0 0px 25px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 200px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.0);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.0);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.0);
    -o-transform: scale(1.0);
    transform: scale(1.0); 
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 500ms;
    border:2px solid;
    height:50px;
}

.content > .contact {
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
    -moz-border-radius:10px;
    -khtml-border-radius:10px;
    border-radius:10px;
    padding:5px;
    margin-right:15px;
    margin-top:8px;
    box-shadow:0 0px 25px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 200px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.0);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.0);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.0);
    -o-transform: scale(1.0);
    transform: scale(1.0); 
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 500ms;
    border:2px solid red;
    height:10px;
}
```

Comment: I dont know if it matters but the class applies to the images only not to the whole div. I have tried this solution but it doesnt work either

Comment: When you use a class and specify it for div, it does work for div. If you want it for img just give that class name to img.

Comment: Yes that will be the best way indeed, but unfortunately I do not control the IMG tags, since I am using a code provided by google maps for inserting a map. As I am inserting the map inside the content div the image style applies also to the images that the map is created by.

Comment: I guess you are missing <img/> tag in you code. Take a look at given fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/e4Dmv/. And try to run it after deleting <img/> tag as well.

Comment: Just altered your code including the exact script and see the result :) http://jsfiddle.net/e4Dmv/1/

Comment: That is because of the animations used in div class

Comment: I know that... I have trying to remove everything from the contact class, but still the content class applies to it

Comment: Yes, but now the call does not apply to the content div as well
http://jsfiddle.net/e4Dmv/3/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51008/discussion-between-largan-and-rs26)

Answer (score 1):

You can use direct child operator `>`

So change your css to:

```
div.content >  img {
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
    -moz-border-radius:10px;
    -khtml-border-radius:10px;
    border-radius:10px;
    padding:5px;
    margin-right:15px;
    margin-top:8px;
    box-shadow:0 0px 25px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 200px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.0);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.0);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.0);
    -o-transform: scale(1.0);
    transform: scale(1.0); 
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 500ms;
} /* Will only apply for images inside content div and not contact div */

div.contact > img {
  /* This styles will only be applied to images in contact div */
}
```

`div.content img` means any image that is inside `div.contact`

Comment: I have tried that and it doesnt work. When I put " > " the style is not appear even in the content div

Answer (score 0):

Cascading stylesheets means the former css cascades to all its children.

`div.content img` means "for any img-tag anywhere inside a div with the class content".

You need to add a specifier to the formers img-tag if you don't want it on the latter, or actively overwriting/resetting each property on the latter.